# Python range around a cell value

Tags: python, dataframe

First of all, thx for all the answers I already found here. I'm just starting with python and still have a lot to learn :)

I have some big dataframe with datetimes, and the last column is boolean when some part of the machine is moving. I want to keep all rows where 'Tel_4_omhoog' == 1 and everything from 2 sec before and 2 sec extra after... ( see example: keep data from index 3133 to 3180, full data is about 25000 lines each hour )

```
                     DateTime  Tel_1_omhoog
3131  2022-02-28 06:06:19.211           0.0
3132  2022-02-28 06:06:19.311           0.0
3133  2022-02-28 06:06:19.391           0.0
3134  2022-02-28 06:06:19.511           0.0
3135  2022-02-28 06:06:19.609           0.0
3136  2022-02-28 06:06:19.686           0.0
3137  2022-02-28 06:06:19.810           0.0
3138  2022-02-28 06:06:19.906           0.0
3139  2022-02-28 06:06:19.986           0.0
3140  2022-02-28 06:06:20.030           0.0
3141  2022-02-28 06:06:20.107           0.0
3142  2022-02-28 06:06:20.205           0.0
3143  2022-02-28 06:06:20.285           0.0
3144  2022-02-28 06:06:20.403           0.0
3145  2022-02-28 06:06:20.503           0.0
3146  2022-02-28 06:06:20.585           0.0
3147  2022-02-28 06:06:20.703           0.0
3148  2022-02-28 06:06:20.804           0.0
3149  2022-02-28 06:06:20.884           0.0
3150  2022-02-28 06:06:21.004           0.0
3151  2022-02-28 06:06:21.024           0.0
3152  2022-02-28 06:06:21.103           0.0
3153  2022-02-28 06:06:21.201           0.0
3154  2022-02-28 06:06:21.322           0.0
3155  2022-02-28 06:06:21.383           1.0
3156  2022-02-28 06:06:21.402           1.0
3157  2022-02-28 06:06:21.502           1.0
3158  2022-02-28 06:06:21.541           0.0
3159  2022-02-28 06:06:21.622           0.0
3160  2022-02-28 06:06:21.701           0.0
3161  2022-02-28 06:06:21.801           0.0
3162  2022-02-28 06:06:21.921           0.0
3163  2022-02-28 06:06:21.999           0.0
3164  2022-02-28 06:06:22.020           0.0
3165  2022-02-28 06:06:22.100           0.0
3166  2022-02-28 06:06:22.222           0.0
3167  2022-02-28 06:06:22.301           0.0
3168  2022-02-28 06:06:22.400           0.0
3169  2022-02-28 06:06:22.520           0.0
3170  2022-02-28 06:06:22.600           0.0
3171  2022-02-28 06:06:22.699           0.0
3172  2022-02-28 06:06:22.816           0.0
3173  2022-02-28 06:06:22.899           0.0
3174  2022-02-28 06:06:23.000           0.0
3175  2022-02-28 06:06:23.020           0.0
3176  2022-02-28 06:06:23.119           0.0
3177  2022-02-28 06:06:23.199           0.0
3178  2022-02-28 06:06:23.298           0.0
3179  2022-02-28 06:06:23.418           0.0
3180  2022-02-28 06:06:23.498           0.0
3181  2022-02-28 06:06:23.597           0.0
3182  2022-02-28 06:06:23.716           0.0
3183  2022-02-28 06:06:23.798           0.0
```

I made something that keeps 5 rows before and 5 rows after( long version )

```
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp1'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-5)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp2'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-4)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp3'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-3)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp4'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-2)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp5'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-1)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp6'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(1)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp7'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(2)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp8'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(3)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp9'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(4)
db['Tel_1_cyclus_temp10'] = db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(5)

db.insert(1, 'Tel_1_cyclus_behouden', 1*((db.Tel_1_omhoog==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp1==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp2==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp3==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp4==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp5==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp6==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp7==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp8==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp9==1) | (db.Tel_1_cyclus_temp10==1)))
```

same but shorter ( and a lot slower ):

```
db.insert(1, 'Tel_1_cyclus_behouden', 1*((db.Tel_1_omhoog==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-5)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-4)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-3)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-2)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(-1)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(1)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(2)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(3)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(4)==1) | (db.Tel_1_omhoog.shift(5)==1)))
```

i need it to work with + / - 2 sec instead

editted : added text example of dataframe, added tag DataFrame

Comment: provide the data as text

Comment: What is `db`? It's best to add a tag to the type of db you're using, to bring your question to the attention of people who use the same.

Comment: i guess my question is not so easy, or didn't i explain it well enough? :(